# R, haven_labelled: Get label as value

Tags: r

I have a vector with the following structure:

```
structure(c(2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
8, 2, 3, 1, 8, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 12, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 4, 1, 4, 7, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 8, 1, 3, 3, 21, 
4, 2, 9, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 5, 
1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 23, 2, NA, NA, NA), label = "Please indicate the year and month of business establishment. - year", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 0L, class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(`2021` = 1, `2020` = 2, `2019` = 3, 
`2018` = 4, `2017` = 5, `2016` = 6, `2015` = 7, `2014` = 8, `2013` = 9, 
`2012` = 10, `2011` = 11, `2010` = 12, `2009` = 13, `2008` = 14, 
`2007` = 15, `2006` = 16, `2005` = 17, `2004` = 18, `2003` = 19, 
`2002` = 20, `2001` = 21, `2000` = 22, `1999` = 23, `1998` = 24, 
`1997` = 25, `1996` = 26, `1995` = 27, `1994` = 28, `1993` = 29, 
`1992` = 30, `1991` = 31, `1990` = 32, `1989` = 33, `1988` = 34, 
`1987` = 35, `1986` = 36, `1985` = 37, `1984` = 38, `1983` = 39, 
`1982` = 40, `1981` = 41, `1980` = 42, `1979` = 43, `1978` = 44, 
`1977` = 45, `1976` = 46, `1975` = 47, `1974` = 48, `1973` = 49, 
`1972` = 50, `1971` = 51, `1970` = 52, `1969` = 53, `1968` = 54, 
`1967` = 55, `1966` = 56, `1965` = 57))
```

What I would like to have is a new vector with each value replaced by its label. So, for example, the first four entries in the new column would be (instead of 2, 6, 3, 6...) "2020", "2016", "2019", "2016"...

Any ideas on how to solve this economically?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
names(attr(df,"labels")[match(df,attr(df,"labels"))])
  [1] "2020" "2016" "2019" "2016" "2021" "2017" "2021" "2021" "2019" "2019" "2021" "2020" "2019"
 [14] "2021" "2019" "2020" "2019" "2014" "2020" "2019" "2021" "2014" "2021" "2021" "2019" "2021"
 [27] "2018" "2019" "2019" "2010" "2021" "2018" "2018" "2019" "2019" "2020" "2021" "2020" "2019"
 [40] "2021" "2018" "2015" "2018" "2021" "2018" "2015" "2019" "2020" "2019" "2020" "2018" "2021"
 [53] "2019" "2018" "2019" "2018" "2020" "2020" "2020" "2020" "2018" "2021" "2021" "2021" "2018"
 [66] "2020" "2021" "2018" "2021" "2021" "2021" "2021" "2018" "2020" "2014" "2021" "2019" "2019"
 [79] "2001" "2018" "2020" "2013" "2021" "2018" "2019" "2021" "2021" "2020" "2020" "2020" "2018"
 [92] "2019" "2018" "2018" "2018" "2018" "2021" "2020" "2020" "2017" "2021" "2021" "2020" "2018"
[105] "2018" "2019" "2017" "2021" "2020" "1999" "2020" NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: thanks, attr() totally escaped my mind :)